# running this code halts my while loop

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
$q1 = mysql_query("select in_time, out_time  from $att_tbl where fk_eid = '$e_id' and a_date = '$dts'");
$r1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
$intime = $r1['in_time'];
$outtime = $r1['out_time'];
```

In the above code '$e_id' is a normal id used to specify users and '$dts' is date in the format YYYY-MM-DD . But when i use this code it halts my parent while loop and if i comment this code my while loop runs fine. I have never seen such behavior. Why is this happening? What is wrong with this code ?

EDIT : this is the full rough code

```
$q1 = mysql_query("select ids from $emp_data where lft = '0' order by emp_id");
while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
{
$e_id = $r1['ids'];
$htmldata = '';
$filename = "$e_id-$months-$years.html";
$date =time () ;
$day = date('d', $date) ;
$month = date('m', $date) ;
$year = date('Y', $date) ;
$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year) ;
$title = date('F', $first_day) ;
$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day) ; 
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday')); 
$day_before_yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday - 1 day'));

switch($day_of_week)
{   
 case "Sun": $blank = 0; break; 
 case "Mon": $blank = 1; break; 
 case "Tue": $blank = 2; break; 
 case "Wed": $blank = 3; break; 
 case "Thu": $blank = 4; break; 
 case "Fri": $blank = 5; break; 
 case "Sat": $blank = 6; break; 
}
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ; 
$htmldata.="<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/cal.css\" type=\"text/css\"><table id=\"mct1\" class=\"ct1 cl1 cp4 cd2 mct\" cellspacing=0>";
$htmldata.="<tr><th> $title $year </th></tr>";
$htmldata.="<tr><td class=\"cbm cba cmi\"><table class=\"ca ca2\"><tr class=\"cl\"><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td class=\"cr\">Sat</td></tr>";
$day_count = 1;
$htmldata.="<tr>";
while ( $blank > 0 ) 
{ 
    $htmldata.="<td>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    $blank = $blank-1; 
    $day_count++;
} 
$day_num = 1;
while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ) 
{ 
    $dts = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$year-$month-$day_num"));
    if(strtotime($dts) <= strtotime($today))
    {
        // $q1 = mysql_query("select in_time, out_time  from $att_tbl where fk_eid = '$e_id' and a_date = '$dts'");
        // $r1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
        // $intime = $r1['in_time'];
        // $outtime = $r1['out_time'];
    }
    $bgclr = '';
    $weekday = date('D', strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day_num));
    if($weekday == 'Sun')
    {
        $bgclr = "bgcolor = \"pink\"";
    }
    $htmldata.="<td class=\"cr\" $bgclr><div class=\"ccd co4\">$day_num <br><font size=\"2\"> $intime <br> $outtime </font></div></td>"; 
    $day_num++; 
    $day_count++;
    if ($day_count > 7)
    {
        $htmldata.="</tr><tr>";
        $day_count = 1;
    }
} 
while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 ) 
{
    $htmldata.="<td>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    $day_count++; 
} 
$htmldata.="</tr></tbody></table></td></tr></table>"; 

$myFile = "$filename";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $htmldata;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
}
```

I have commented the code that is halting the whole while loop so that it can be easily seen

Comment: What is `$att_tbl`? If that does not have any errors, you could always check in the `error_log` file.

Comment: If you run the SQL command directly on the database, is it quick?

Comment: Your script could have been halted due to the fact that `in_time` and `out_time` do not exist in your array.

Comment: it would have been better if you added the code of the parent loop as well :|

Comment: ya Query took 0.0004 secs only. I also check mysql_error but there's no error

Comment: i have added the full code now Plz see

Comment: off topic but important: Please note that the `mysql_xx()` functions are obsolete, and you are **strongly** recommended to replace them. The PHP manual suggests using either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library instead.

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script could have been halted due to the fact that `in_time` and `out_time` do not exist in your array. Otherwise, there is no problem to your query unless you tell us what you have been assigning to the variables.

As I have mentioned in the comments, check in the `error_log` file, which resides in the same directory as this PHP script.

Also, is your parent loop also something along the lines of:

`while ($foo = @mysql_fetch_array($q1))`

If it is, then that might be your error. You are resetting the value of `$q1` inside the while loop, therefore possibly terminating the loop.

**UPDATE:** Now that you posted your code, I know your exact error:

These are your first two lines of code, used to run the main `while` loop:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("select ids from $emp_data where lft = '0' order by emp_id");
while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
```

Notice that you used `$q1` to reference the query. Now down in that piece of code, inside a nested `while` loop:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("select in_time, out_time  from $att_tbl where fk_eid = '$e_id' and a_date = '$dts'");
```

You used `$q1` again. The interpreter thought that you meant to change the variable value, but instead you wanted to initialize another variable called `$q1`.

Okay, after all that, all you need to do is write this for your code:

```
$q2 = mysql_query("select in_time, out_time  from $att_tbl where fk_eid = '$e_id' and a_date = '$dts'");
$r2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2);
$intime = $r2['in_time'];
$outtime = $r2['out_time'];
```

And just change your references anywhere else.

Comment: OMG !! That was so stupid of me :p i always use different variables but as i was doing just rough work on it so didnt took care and see how much time i have wasted on it sheh!! Thanks a lot think123 my code runs fine now  :D

Comment: @user1654147 That's good to know. Any more questions and the Stack Overflow community will be delighted to help.

Answer (score 0):

You said that your query is inside a parent loop. This means that you're running the query multiple times. It is good practice not to place queries inside loops for this very reason.

For example, the (bad) piece of code below will run 1000 queries.

```
$i = 0; 
while($i <= 1000){
    mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE user_id = '$i'");
    $i++;
}
```

Because the piece of code above is not using prepared statements, each query requires a round-trip to the MySQL server.

Comment: this code is generating a calendar similar to attendance calendars and for that i need to check whether a user has some data in its table for that very particular date and thats why this query is inside the loop and it will run just once in 24 hours

Comment: echo out the result of $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ; just to be sure.

Comment: $days_in_month is displaying correct value as per this month i.e. 30 and there are just 7 rows currently in $emp_data table and 10 rows in that $att_tbl table as i was just doing rough work here.

Comment: Is there query actually working? As in: After the script has run, is it correct?

Comment: ya its running fine now. I did such stupid mistake in hurry - i have assigned same $q1 to both the queries and in the inner while loop program took it as if i wanted to initialize $q1 with new values and thats what was halting the main while loop. I have changed the variable and it has started running fine. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("select in_time, out_time  from $att_tbl where fk_eid = '$e_id' and a_date = '$dts'");
while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
{
$intime = $r1['in_time'];
$outtime = $r1['out_time'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to run that query inside a loop? Can't you get all the $e_id variables first as an array and change the query to `select in_time, out_time  from $att_tbl where fk_eid IN (... all your $e_id values formatted for SQL...) and a_date='$e_id'`. Then you'd loop through the result set instead of firing off (potentially) hundreds of SELECTs to MySQL.

You can format your $e_id array with this:

```
$sqlString = implode("','", $e_id);
$sql = "select in_time, out_time  from $att_tbl where fk_eid IN ('$sqlString') and a_date='$e_id';
```

For debugging purposes, you should always have error reporting switched on. You would be able to see immediately what the problem is, I think.